# Log4j logs hidden or swallowed when deployed to CloudFoundry

Tags: log4j, cloud-foundry

I've just deployed my first app to CloudFoundry, and I use log4j. When I deploy the app to a local tomcat server, the logs print just fine as all is well. But, when I use the "vmc logs " command to get the logs from the instance on CloudFoundry, I only get the tomcat initialization logs and this message:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Anything further that I've printed with log4j is not visible. System.out.println messages show up, but no log4j messages.

I've placed my log4j.properties file in my WEB-INF directory, and here are its contents:

```
# Set root logger level to DEBUG and its only appender to A1.
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, A1
# A1 is set to be a ConsoleAppender.
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
# A1 uses PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p %-35c{1} %m%n
log4j.logger.org.springframework=WARN
```

My logger object is created as would probably be expected in my classes:

```
private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);
```

Any suggestions as to what configuration I'm missing to have my log4j logs show up in my CloudFoundry logs? Or am I retrieving them incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is Log4j set to output to STDOUT by default? 'vmc logs' will only return the contents of STDOUT, STDERR and the staging log files.

If you app is logging to a different file then use 'vmc file' to view the content.

Comment: It seems to me that for some reason, when it's deployed to CloudFoundry, the app can't find the log4j.properties file to begin with. I've placed it in my web-inf folder, so it should be able to find it. Again, if I deploy to a local tomcat server, the logs print just fine, and I don't see any warning about log4j not being configured properly.

Comment: Just to clarify, the file needs to be on the classpath, so in WEB-INF/classes (as opposed to just WEB-INF). The warning message you get clearly is a sign that the file can't be found. Also, make sue that it is indeed in your war file (it could be that in dev environment, it is made available by some magic, maybe in your IDE, or whatever -- this could be a lead, without having more context)

Comment: Thank you both for your replies, they both fixed an issue I was having, and everything seems to be running the way I'd expect now.